# NODE - Sequelize: search with special characters

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my database, for instance, the names are saved as "José, Jósê, Jôsê". But how can I return all these results when I type "jose" only.

I have this code:

`return await User.findAl({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: 'jose' } }})`

```
           .In my database, for instance, the names are saved as "José, Jósê, Jôsê". But how can I return all these results when I type "jose".
```

I have this code:

`return await User.findAl({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: 'jose' } }})`

Comment: Which db are you using? mysql or postgresql?

Comment: I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The operator [Op.like] is case-sensitive. You can replace it with [Op.iLike] (case insensitive)

The statement can be written as follow

```
return User.findAl({ where: { name: { [Op.iLike]: 'jose' } }}) // no need to use await as async function's return statement always returns a promise.
```

N.B: This will work for postgre only.

For MySQL and other db, you can find more details from [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators)